# Explain why it is not necessary to use numerical method to find the two solutions of the equation.

Tags: numerical-methods

This question I havent been able to understand. I am self studying and have no teacher to ask so I have been stuck for the past hour and don't get this is the full question the part I don't get is 14 c

[image]
Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your screen shot is blurry and a bit dim. Please re-do with a clearly focused and well lit version.

Comment: Because a general formula to find the roots of a cubic exists. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#General_cubic_formula

Comment: If you know one of the roots $r$, you can divide the polynomial by $x-r$ to get a quadratic with the other two roots, which you can then easily find.

Comment: @coffeemath i fixed it do you think you can look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (a) of the problem: $p(x)=20x^3+8x^2-7x-3$ then $p(.5)=-2$ and $p(1)=+18.$ So since the sign is opposite at $.5$ and $1,$ there must be a root between them.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If a cubic polynomial $f(x)$ has exactly two roots, then one of them must be a double root, so that it is also a root of the derivative $f'(x)$, which is a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: I am confused so this is the answer.

Comment: @maryjames: Try it! Compute $f'(x)$ and solve the quadratic equation $f'(x)=0$. One of the two solutions you get should also be a (double) root to $f(x)=0$, and then you should be able to find the other root easily.